# Rails & Activerecord: how to handle a fixed number of record in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have to solve a problem.

I have a CMS with three type of contents: Video, Gallery and News.
Every type of content is a different class in my Rails app, and now I have to create a json with some selected content. In my json I have also to manage the order.

So I create a table with these fields:

- content_type
- content_title
- content_url
- content_image
- content_date
- order

I use this table to generate the json ordering by order.

To fill my table I add to my News, Video and Gallery class the flag "add_to_json" and a datetime attribute called "added_to_json_table"

Every 5 minute I have a rake task that check for the presence of the flag, and if datetime is nil create a record a new record in the table.

I'm using the rake task because only published and selected content must go in the json.

My question is: how can I handle the number of items in my table? I want to keep the item number fixed to 15, so I can add a view to manage the order.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to:

- periodically (every 5 minutes) identify all new flagged content, and add it to the table
- but only have 15 entries in the table at one time

does that sum it up? If so, I'd just add some logic to my Rake task to *clear out* the oldest entries until there's only 15 remaining.

Try that and see if it gets you the behavior you expect. If so, then you'll want to think about efficiency too: if more than 30-50 new content records are being created within a 5-minute span, then the Rake task will end up adding tons of new entries only to delete them right after. There are lots of ways to prevent that, let me know if you want help with ideas.

Comment: You are right, but I prefear to manage the table without task. I'm thinking about a callback...

Comment: Sounds good. I happen to hate callbacks because I think they encourage "invisible logic" where some action triggers a completely unrelated consequence and leaves the troubleshooter pulling his/her hair out, so for my hypothetical sake, please consider documenting to make the callbacks as visible as possible. ;-)